# Mongodb php extension not loading. Linux centos 6 Plesk onyx php 5.6.31

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, plesk, php-mongodb

I have installed the lastest mongodb php driver on linux centos 6 with plesk onyx using the following commands.

```
yum install plesk-php56-devel make gcc openssl-devel

/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/pecl install mongodb

echo "mongodb.so" > /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.d/mongodb.ini

plesk bin php_handler --reread
```

I have also added extension=mongodb.so to the php.ini file.
I also changed the cli version from php 5.3 to 5.6 before running the install as php needed to be at least 5.4 for the install to continue.

The mongodb section in now in my phpinfo() page. However the extension is not loaded when I test it in a php page.

When I try to reinstall I get this message:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/opt/plesk/php/5.6/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so' -
>   /opt/plesk/php/5.6/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   pecl/mongodb is already installed and is the same as the released
>   version 1.2.9 install failed

Also, the line that says /opt/plesk/php/5.6/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so
refers to mongo.so when in actual fact the file present in the modules folder is mongodb.so

Does anyone have any suggestions or experience with this please?

Answer (score 0):

For those facing the same issue. This was fixed by changing the extension name in the following file /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.d/mongodb.ini  from mongo.so to mongodb.so

And then remember to use the new mongo driver class ie MongoDB\Driver\